# Type alias resolving to any after import

Tags: typescript, generics, visual-studio-code, typescript-generics, type-alias

I have a type `AddEmailToMailingList` declared as so

```
// addEmailToMailingList.ts

type SuccessResponse =
  | {
      success: false;
      message: string;
      code: number;
    }
  | {
      success: true;
    };

export type AddEmailToMailingList = (data: {
  email: string;
}) => Promise<SuccessResponse>;
```

this is imported and re-exported via some generics by another file

```
// types.ts

import { AddEmailToMailingList } from "./functions/addEmailToMailingList";

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
type DuckFunction = (...args: any) => any;

type ThenArgRecursive<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U>
  ? ThenArgRecursive<U>

type HttpsCallable<T extends DuckFunction> = (
  ...args: Parameters<T>
) => Promise<{
  readonly data: ThenArgRecursive<ReturnType<T>>;
}>;

export type CallableAddEmailToMailingList = HttpsCallable<AddEmailToMailingList>;
```

When I import this `CallableAddEmailToMailingList` type in another package in my workspace it inferes the type correctly.

This is the correct type inference:

```
// VSCode type inference

(alias) type CallableAddEmailToMailingList = (data: {
    email: string;
}) => Promise<{
    readonly data: SuccessResponse;
}>
```

Now I want to move the type `SuccessResponse` into its own file so other functions can import and use it.

```
// addEmailToMailingList.ts

import { SuccessResponse } from "@/typesInternal";

export type AddEmailToMailingList = (data: {
  email: string;
}) => Promise<SuccessResponse>;
```

Now the package where I import the `CallableAddEmailToMailingList` type no longer has the correct type inference, it has completely lost what `SuccessResponse` is and it turns to `any`

This is what the type inference now is after importing `CallableAddEmailToMailingList`:

```
// VSCode type inference

(alias) type CallableAddEmailToMailingList = (data: {
    email: string;
}) => Promise<{
    readonly data: any;
}>
```

However it is still correct when hovering over `CallableAddEmailToMailingList` in the types.ts file where it is declared.

I can't figure out any logical reason for this, the only way to prevent it is to not import `SuccessResponse` and declare it in the same file as the function.

Is this a bug in Typescript or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you do a minimal stackblitz? I have a hard time following the scenario

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-olwews?file=types.ts

However the type inference is not matching VS Code in this repro, the type inference here is also lost in the `types.ts` file when you hover over `CallableAddEmailToMailingList`. Whereas in VS Code the inference is correct for me in `types.ts` and just incorrect when hovering over `CallableAddEmailToMailingList` in `index.ts`.

Comment: Also this repro I'm not importing `SuccessResponse` and it is happening regardless. Wherease in VS Code if I declare `SuccessResponse` in the same file, the inference works as it should.

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem, using the latest version of TypeScript (currently 4.5.5) and in WebStorm, rather than Visual Studio. I initially thought that it was to do with circular dependencies, but I've checked my graph, and there's nothing to be seen.